# Android app crashes on FragmentActivity.java android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult

Tags: android, crash, fragment

in my app their is no FragmentActivity.java but crash report give me the following error

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms&pcampaignid=gcore_8487000--- flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1647)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3415)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3376)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3611)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3579)
   at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17373)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5056)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:840)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

i don't know what and where actually the problem is and the most of the time this crash happens in Redmi phones

Comment: post your java code

Comment: post your Main activity java code and onClick listener code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439313/no-activity-found-to-handle-market-uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception occurs if device does not have the google play installed(no `Activity` to handle this `intent`) - you can just try to open url in `browser` in that case:

you can use google play package name:`com.android.vending`

```
String pakcage_name="com.android.vending";

 public static void open_google_play(Context context) {
    try {
        //open in play store app directly
        context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + pakcage_name)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        //open in browser
        openBrowser(context, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + pakcage_name);
    }
}

public static void openBrowser(Context context, String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    if (null != intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager())) {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

use it as during `button` click write this method:

```
open_google_play(Activity.this);
```

Comment: but if i don't have google play service i don't have code for it but it automatically handle and a screen with button GET GOOGLE PLAY SERVICE is display...so where to check if user has clicked on that button?

Comment: @JuliaWilliams i don;t follow!! clicked on what button?

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/l77yo18nl/6226f56e/


see above image it comes when their is google play service is not updated
and if google play service is not installed then button name is "Get Google play service"

if user click on that button and if their is no play store installed then app crashes

Answer (score 0):

It says that you have no activity to handle it.
That is google play store is missing. Try to put your code in try `catch` `block`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to launch an `Intent` to view the Google Play Store but it does not exist on the phone, causing a crash. You should first check that the intent can be resolved, like so:

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent)
}
```